# Upload data from memory to SFTP server using SSH.NET

Tags: c#, .net, sftp, ssh.net

I am hoping to write PDF's directly to SFTP site.  The PDF's are generated from `ReportExecutionService.Render` (SSRS).

```
ReportExecutionService rsExec = new ReportExecutionService();
```

I have been able to write the files locally using `FileStream`.  I am generating millions of files, so I am hoping to write them directly on SFTP using SSH.NET.  What is the syntax for taking the `rsExec.Render` result and writing to SFTP using SSH.NET?

```
string deviceInfo = null;
string extension;
string encoding;
string mimeType;
ConsoleApp2.ReportExecution2005.Warning[] warnings = null;
string[] streamIDs = null;
string format = "PDF";

Byte[] results =
    rsExec.Render(
        format, deviceInfo, out extension, out mimeType, out encoding,
        out warnings, out streamIDs);
FileStream stream = File.OpenWrite("C:\\test.pdf");
stream.Write(results, 0, results.Length);
stream.Close();
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Wrap the `byte` array to a `MemoryStream` and use `SftpClient.UploadFile` to upload it

```
var client = new SftpClient(host, port, username, password);
client.Connect();
var stream = new MemoryStream(results);
client.UploadFile(stream, "/remote/path/my.pdf");
```

---

Though most data-manipulation libraries can use the `Stream` API directly. That would be more efficient to use, instead of copying the data over via `byte[]` array.