# Is it possible to upload a CSV file to an SFTP server directly from a MemoryStream?

Tags: c#, csv, sftp, memorystream, ssh.net

Whenever I try to upload a file to the SFTP server with the `.csv` file extension the only thing within that file is `System.IO.MemoryStream`. If it's a `.txt` extension it will have all the values in the file. I can manually convert the `.txt` to `.csv` and it will be fine. Is it possible to upload it directly to the SFTP server as a CSV file?

The SFTP Service is using the SSH.NET library by Renci.

**Using statement:**

```cs
using (var stream = csvFileWriter.Write(data, new CsvMapper()))
{
    byte[] file = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(stream.ToString());
    sftpService.Put(SftpCredential.Credentials.Id, file, $"/file.csv");
}
```

**SFTP service:**

```cs
public void Put(int credentialId, byte[] source, string destination)
{
    using (SftpClient client = new SftpClient(GetConnectionInfo(credentialId)))
    {
        ConnectClient(client);

        using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream(source))
        {
            client.BufferSize = 4 * 1024; // bypass Payload error large files
            client.UploadFile(memoryStream, destination);
        }
        DisconnectClient(client);
    }
```

---

**Solution:**
The `csvFilerWriter` I was using returned a `Stream` not a `MemoryStream`, so by switching the `csvFileWriter` and `CsvPut()` over to `MemoryStream` it worked.

**Updated using statement:**

```
using (var stream = csvFileWriter.Write(data, new CsvMapper()))
{
    stream.Position = 0;
    sftpService.CsvPut(SftpCredential.credemtoa;s.Id, stream, $"/file.csv");
}
```

**Updated SFTP service:**

```
public void CsvPut(int credentialId, MemoryStream source, string destination)
{
    using (SftpClient client = new SftpClient(GetConnectionInfo(credentialId)))
    {
        ConnectClient(client);

        client.BufferSize = 4 * 1024; //bypass Payload error large files
        client.UploadFile(source, destination);

        DisconnectClient(client);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the `csvFileWriter.Write` already returns `MemoryStream`. And its `ToString` returns `"System.IO.MemoryStream"` string. That's the root source of your problem.

Aditionally, as you already have the `MemoryStream`, its an overkill to copy it to yet another `MemoryStream`, upload it directly. You are copying the data over and over again, it's just a waste of memory.

Like this:

```
var stream = csvFileWriter.Write(data, new CsvMapper());
stream.Position = 0;
client.UploadFile(stream, destination);
```

---

See also:

- [Upload data from memory to SFTP server using SSH.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45945512/850848)
- [When uploading memory stream with contents created by csvhelper using SSH.NET to SFTP server, the uploaded file is empty](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60691827/850848)

---

A simple test code to upload in-memory data:

```
var stream = new MemoryStream();
stream.Write(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("this is test"));
stream.Position = 0;

using (var client = new SftpClient("example.com", "username", "password"))
{
    client.Connect();
    client.UploadFile(stream, "/remote/path/file.txt");
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can avoid the unnecessary using of memory  stream like this:

```
        using (var sftp = new SftpClient(GetConnectionInfo(SftpCredential.GetById(credentialId).Id))))
        {
           sftp.Connect();
           using (var uplfileStream = System.IO.File.OpenRead(fileName))
           {
              sftp.UploadFile(uplfileStream, fileName, true);
           }
           sftp.Disconnect();
        }
```

Comment: It does not look like that the OP is uploading a physical file.

Comment: What do you mean. This piece of code should be wrapped in method and should have several checks before be able to use it. I only demonstrate the idea that the file can be opened as stream and that stream can be passed as parameter to UploadFile to be uploaded.

Comment: But there's no file. OP uploads data generated directly in memory.