# Getting "Invalid path" when sending MemoryStream from Amazon S3 bucket to a remote server using SFTP in C#

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, sftp, ssh.net

I'm working on logic to retrieve a file from an Amazon S3 Bucket and then send it to a remote server using SFTP.

However, I'm not able to send the file because I don't have a path value - i.e., since my file is in S3, I don't have a path for it my local machine.

This is my method to send a file - it's inside a class called `SftpService`:

```
public async Task SendFile(SftpRequest request, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
{
    // Connect to server
    SftpClient client = new SftpClient(request.Host, request.Port, request.Username, request.Password);
    client.Connect();

    if (!client.IsConnected)
    {
        throw new SftpClientException("SFTP Connection was not complete.");
    }

    // Create an object of File Stream and pass a temp file path.
    var tempFilePath = Path.GetTempFileName();
    FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(tempFilePath, FileMode.Open);

    // Copy the MemoryStream (from S3) to the FileStream
    request.RefundFile.CopyTo(fileStream);
    fileStream.Close();

    // Upload the file. [TBD] What's the path for the file? (it is a MemoryStream)
    client.UploadFile(fileStream, tempFilePath);

    // Dispose the object by calling dispose method of sftpClient once the file has uploaded.
    client.Dispose();
}
```

Now, I'm trying to perform a test on this method (using NUnit).

```
[SetUp]
public void Setup()
{
    _sut = new SftpService(); //class
}

[Test]
public async Task SftpService_ShouldSendFileToServer_Success()
{
    var request = MockSftpRequest();

    await _sut.SendFile(request);
}

private SftpRequest MockSftpRequest()
{
    var serverMock = new ServerOptions()
    {
        BaseAddress = "195.144.107.198",
        Username = "demo",
        Password = "password",
    };

    // Create a mock MemoryStream
    var s3FileMock = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("This is a mock of the s3 file."));

    SftpRequest request = new SftpRequest(serverMock)
    {
        RefundFile = refundFileMock,
        Port = 22,
    };

    return request;
}
```

When running the test, I'm getting this error:

> Message: Renci.SshNet.Common.SftpPathNotFoundException : Invalid path.

---

So, my question is: how can I achieve to send a `MemoryStream` over SFTP, without a path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have both parameters of `SftpClient.UploadFile` wrong.

1. Your immediate issue it that you are passing local path to the second parameter of `SftpClient.UploadFile`. Why? Obviously one parameter must be for *local* file/data and the other for *remote*. You are already passing *local* data to the first argument. So `SftpClient.UploadFile` does not need the *local* path anymore. It needs the *remote* path.
2. Why are you saving the `[Memory]Stream` to a temporary file only to open the file as another `[File]Stream` to pass it to `SftpClient.UploadFile`? Pass the `MemoryStream` to the `SftpClient.UploadFile` straight away.

```
client.UploadFile(request.RefundFile, "/remote/path/file");
```

---

Related question: [Upload data from memory to SFTP server using SSH.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45945512/850848)

Comment: Yes, you are right. For some reason I was thinking the parameters for `UploadFile` were still related to the file I had (from S3), not related to how the file was going to be handled in the server - but it makes total sense for the path to be in the server. I will update the question with the resolution.